# MS ACCESS: INNER JOIN Always TRUE (e.g. ON TRUE | ON 1 = 1)

Tags: ms-access, inner-join

---

Hi Everyone,

I am trying to do a calculation between two tables and want the **INNER JOIN to be always TRUE**.

However, when I enter in **MS ACCESS** the error says the **"JOIN-expression is not supported"**.

Any idea how I can deal with it to make it work? Or does MS ACCESS not allow ON TRUE expression in general?

**SELECT
A.Part,
(Sqr(([T.R_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LX])^2+([T.H_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LY])^2)) AS ABSTAND
INTO ABSTAND_CALC
FROM AVANI_FPF_SSR0 AS A
INNER JOIN G_IVL_KOORDINATEN AS T
ON 1 = 1;**

Many thanks, regards
Sina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` on everything is a cross join.

In Access SQL, we write cross joins by omitting the `JOIN` clause entirely, and separating the tables by a comma:

```
SELECT A.Part, (Sqr(([T.R_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LX])^2+([T.H_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LY])^2)) AS ABSTAND INTO ABSTAND_CALC 
FROM AVANI_FPF_SSR0 AS A, G_IVL_KOORDINATEN AS T;
```